# How to get a specific part of a JSON response

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, json

Hi so I'm trying to get all the names, the tweet volume and the twitter url for the trending topics in my selected places but I'm new to JSON and can't find a way to only select those parts.

```
const Twit = require('twit');
const params = {
    id: '23424829',
    id: '23424975',
    id: '23424977'
};

client.get('trends/place', params, gotData, 3);

function gotData(err, data, response) {
    var tweets = data;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(tweets.trends.name));
}
```

But this doesn't work and if it would work it would only give me the name.

This is the whole thing:

```
[
   {
      "trends":[
         {
            "name":"#SuperTuesday",
            "url":"http://twitter.com`/search?q=%23SuperTuesday",
            "promoted_content":null,
            "query":"%23SuperTuesday",
            "tweet_volume":340393
         },
         {
            "name":"#nashvillestrong",
            "url":"http://twitter.com/search?q=%23nashvillestrong",
            "promoted_content":null,
            "query":"%23nashvillestrong",
            "tweet_volume":15223
         },
         {
            "name":"Donna Brazile",
            "url":"http://twitter.com/search?q=%22Donna+Brazile%22",
            "promoted_content":null,
            "query":"%22Donna+Brazile%22",
            "tweet_volume":95587
         },
         {
            "name":"#VoteWarren",
            "url":"http://twitter.com/search?q=%23VoteWarren",
            "promoted_content":null,
            "query":"%23VoteWarren",
            "tweet_volume":19055
         },
         {
            "name":"Only Fans",
            "url":"http://twitter.com/search?q=%22Only+Fans%22",
            "promoted_content":null,
            "query":"%22Only+Fans%22",
            "tweet_volume":39779
         },
         {
            "name":"#IVoted",
            "url":"http://twitter.com/search?q=%23IVoted",
            "promoted_content":null,
            "query":"%23IVoted",
            "tweet_volume":null
         },
         {
            "name":"Dolan",
            "url":"http://twitter.com/search?q=Dolan",
            "promoted_content":null,
            "query":"Dolan",
            "tweet_volume":21526
         },
         {
            "name":"#VoteBernie",
            "url":"http://twitter.com/search?q=%23VoteBernie",
            "promoted_content":null,
            "query":"%23VoteBernie",
            "tweet_volume":26569
         },
         {
            "name":"Cover 3",
            "url":"http://twitter.com/search?q=%22Cover+3%22",
            "promoted_content":null,
            "query":"%22Cover+3%22",
            "tweet_volume":null
         },
         {
            "name":"Lavar Ball",
            "url":"http://twitter.com/search?q=%22Lavar+Ball%22",
            "promoted_content":null,
            "query":"%22Lavar+Ball%22",
            "tweet_volume":null
         },
         {
            "name":"The Fed",
            "url":"http://twitter.com/search?q=%22The+Fed%22",
            "promoted_content":null,
            "query":"%22The+Fed%22",
            "tweet_volume":44699
         },
         {
            "name":"The Knicks",
            "url":"http://twitter.com/search?q=%22The+Knicks%22",
            "promoted_content":null,
            "query":"%22The+Knicks%22",
            "tweet_volume":25069
         },
         {
            "name":"Baby Pluto",
            "url":"http://twitter.com/search?q=%22Baby+Pluto%22",
            "promoted_content":null,
            "query":"%22Baby+Pluto%22",
            "tweet_volume":65028
         },
         {
            "name":"Snacks",
            "url":"http://twitter.com/search?q=Snacks",
            "promoted_content":null,
            "query":"Snacks",
            "tweet_volume":46097
         },
         {
            "name":"Chris Sale",
            "url":"http://twitter.com/search?q=%22Chris+Sale%22",
            "promoted_content":null,
            "query":"%22Chris+Sale%22",
            "tweet_volume":null
         },
         {
            "name":"I LOVE YOU JIMIN",
            "url":"http://twitter.com/search?q=%22I+LOVE+YOU+JIMIN%22",
            "promoted_content":null,
            "query":"%22I+LOVE+YOU+JIMIN%22",
            "tweet_volume":62801
         },
         {
            "name":"Favorite OST",
            "url":"http://twitter.com/search?q=%22Favorite+OST%22",
            "promoted_content":null,
            "query":"%22Favorite+OST%22",
            "tweet_volume":null
         },
         {
            "name":"Martin Perez",
            "url":"http://twitter.com/search?q=%22Martin+Perez%22",
            "promoted_content":null,
            "query":"%22Martin+Perez%22",
            "tweet_volume":null
         },
         {
            "name":"Brit Hume",
            "url":"http://twitter.com/search?q=%22Brit+Hume%22",
            "promoted_content":null,
            "query":"%22Brit+Hume%22",
            "tweet_volume":10257
         },
         {
            "name":"Putnam County",
            "url":"http://twitter.com/search?q=%22Putnam+County%22",
            "promoted_content":null,
            "query":"%22Putnam+County%22",
            "tweet_volume":null
         },
         {
            "name":"Tejas",
            "url":"http://twitter.com/search?q=Tejas",
            "promoted_content":null,
            "query":"Tejas",
            "tweet_volume":null
         },
         {
            "name":"Kolten Wong",
            "url":"http://twitter.com/search?q=%22Kolten+Wong%22",
            "promoted_content":null,
            "query":"%22Kolten+Wong%22",
            "tweet_volume":null
         },
         {
            "name":"#WithTheseHands",
            "url":"http://twitter.com/search?q=%23WithTheseHands",
            "promoted_content":null,
            "query":"%23WithTheseHands",
            "tweet_volume":28528
         },
         {
            "name":"#Covid_19",
            "url":"http://twitter.com/search?q=%23Covid_19",
            "promoted_content":null,
            "query":"%23Covid_19",
            "tweet_volume":114746
         },
         {
            "name":"#WorldWildlifeDay",
            "url":"http://twitter.com/search?q=%23WorldWildlifeDay",
            "promoted_content":null,
            "query":"%23WorldWildlifeDay",
            "tweet_volume":70315
         },
         {
            "name":"#BidenForPresident",
            "url":"http://twitter.com/search?q=%23BidenForPresident",
            "promoted_content":null,
            "query":"%23BidenForPresident",
            "tweet_volume":22183
         },
         {
            "name":"#OneDreamWithTXT",
            "url":"http://twitter.com/search?q=%23OneDreamWithTXT",
            "promoted_content":null,
            "query":"%23OneDreamWithTXT",
            "tweet_volume":492038
         },
         {
            "name":"#WhyIWasQuarantined",
            "url":"http://twitter.com/search?q=%23WhyIWasQuarantined",
            "promoted_content":null,
            "query":"%23WhyIWasQuarantined",
            "tweet_volume":null
         },
         {
            "name":"#FrozenFoodMonth",
            "url":"http://twitter.com/search?q=%23FrozenFoodMonth",
            "promoted_content":null,
            "query":"%23FrozenFoodMonth",
            "tweet_volume":null
         },
         {
            "name":"#TMobileTuesdays",
            "url":"http://twitter.com/search?q=%23TMobileTuesdays",
            "promoted_content":null,
            "query":"%23TMobileTuesdays",
            "tweet_volume":null
         },
         {
            "name":"#MakesMeSayYes",
            "url":"http://twitter.com/search?q=%23MakesMeSayYes",
            "promoted_content":null,
            "query":"%23MakesMeSayYes",
            "tweet_volume":null
         },
         {
            "name":"#FederalReserve",
            "url":"http://twitter.com/search?q=%23FederalReserve",
            "promoted_content":null,
            "query":"%23FederalReserve",
            "tweet_volume":null
         },
         {
            "name":"#GetJuicy",
            "url":"http://twitter.com/search?q=%23GetJuicy",
            "promoted_content":null,
            "query":"%23GetJuicy",
            "tweet_volume":null
         },
         {
            "name":"#KickItMVTeaser",
            "url":"http://twitter.com/search?q=%23KickItMVTeaser",
            "promoted_content":null,
            "query":"%23KickItMVTeaser",
            "tweet_volume":204056
         },
         {
            "name":"#SweetTalk",
            "url":"http://twitter.com/search?q=%23SweetTalk",
            "promoted_content":null,
            "query":"%23SweetTalk",
            "tweet_volume":null
         },
         {
            "name":"#Tennessee",
            "url":"http://twitter.com/search?q=%23Tennessee",
            "promoted_content":null,
            "query":"%23Tennessee",
            "tweet_volume":null
         },
         {
            "name":"#303Day",
            "url":"http://twitter.com/search?q=%23303Day",
            "promoted_content":null,
            "query":"%23303Day",
            "tweet_volume":null
         },
         {
            "name":"#robinhoodoutage",
            "url":"http://twitter.com/search?q=%23robinhoodoutage",
            "promoted_content":null,
            "query":"%23robinhoodoutage",
            "tweet_volume":null
         },
         {
            "name":"#ratecut",
            "url":"http://twitter.com/search?q=%23ratecut",
            "promoted_content":null,
            "query":"%23ratecut",
            "tweet_volume":null
         },
         {
            "name":"#TravelTuesday",
            "url":"http://twitter.com/search?q=%23TravelTuesday",
            "promoted_content":null,
            "query":"%23TravelTuesday",
            "tweet_volume":null
         },
         {
            "name":"#AuthorMentorMatch",
            "url":"http://twitter.com/search?q=%23AuthorMentorMatch",
            "promoted_content":null,
            "query":"%23AuthorMentorMatch",
            "tweet_volume":null
         }
      ],
      "as_of":"2020-03-03T19:38:33Z",
      "created_at":"2020-03-03T19:35:32Z",
      "locations":[
         {
            "name":"United States",
            "woeid":23424977
         }
      ]
   }
]"
```

Comment: Did you try printing only tweets.trends ?

Comment: I think that when `gotData()` is being called `data` consists of a JSON-encoded string that you are not decoding.

Comment: looking on JSON structure: `const names = data[0].trends.map(t => t.name)` - it would be an array of names. p.s. it is JS, not json related to take "names"

Comment: @Pitto yes I tried printing only tweets.trends but that returned "undefined"

Comment: Thank you so much @andriishupta that worked. If you want to answer this as an answer instead of comment I would be able to give you the answer checkmark thing :D